# Drupal 7 : Themeing nodes when using node_load_mulltiple

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I am loading 10 nodes of different content types and I need to style each node differently.

**The current html output:**

```
<article id="node-2293" class="node node-postit node-promoted contextual-links-region      
node-even clearfix" typeof="sioc:Item foaf:Document" about="/en/number-6-jan-22">
<header class="node-header">
<div class="node-content content"> </div>
<footer class="node-footer">
</article>
```

The problem is node_load_multiple() or node_view_multiple() are giving each node's article an id as per their nid. I want to assign or encapsulate each node in my own div and my own id so that I can style them each one of them.

My Module code:

```
if ($nodes = node_load_multiple($customvishalnodestoshow)) {
$build['nodes'] = node_view_multiple($nodes, 'full');
}
```

How can I implement this ?

Cheers,
Vishal

Comment: What is the logic you are trying to theme them by?  IE, do you have multiple node types and are trying to theme each type differently?  Are you arbitrarily trying to add different themes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to theme different node types differently, thats what node.tpl.php in your theme folder is for.  you can copy the existing node.tpl.php and create one for each node type and write custom HTML there.

For example, if you have node types called 'book', 'story' and 'blog', create these template files:

- node--book.tpl.php
- node--story.tpl.php
- node--blog.tpl.php

Comment: Hi, I am loading 10 nodes of different types on the same page. Not each node on a separate page. So node-book.tpl.php won't work.

Comment: It does not matter whether you are rendering one per page or multiple.  If you trace the API here ( http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_view_multiple/7 ) you will see that node_view_multiple calls node_view, which hooks into the node.tpl.php system.   Its all the same process.